# Wildcard in Ansible in template

Tags: automation, ansible

Does anyone tried to use wildcard in template or in playbook?

The wildcard works in inventory and listing hosts but it's not working in template or in playbook.

Following command works:

```
ansible -i inventory/ec2.py tag_Name_Hbase*  --list-host`
```

but the same thing is not working in playbook.

Example (not working):

```
Node: `{{ {{ ":2181,".join(groups["tag_Name_Zookeeper*"]) }}:2181 }}`
```

Example (working):

```
Node: `{{ {{ ":2181,".join(groups["tag_Name_Zookeeper_Kafka01"]) }}:2181 }}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards for dict key won't work.  You need to iterate over `group.keys()`.

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    Node: |
      {% set o = [] %}
      {%- for i in groups.keys() %}
        {%- if i.startswith("tag_Name_Zookeeper") %}
          {%- for j in groups[i] %}
            {%- if o.append(j+":2181") %}
            {%- endif %}
          {%- endfor %}
        {%- endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ ",".join(o) }}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: Node
      run_once: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
```

hosts:

```
[tag_Name_Zookeeper_1]
a
b
[tag_Name_Zookeeper_2]
c
d
[tag_Name_Zookeeper_3]
e
f
[others]
localhost
```

Sample session:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml 

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

TASK: [debug ] **************************************************************** 
ok: [a -> localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "Node": "a:2181,b:2181,c:2181,d:2181,e:2181,f:2181"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
a                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
b                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
c                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
d                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
e                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
f                          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```